# How can I Get[] a file and keep it in a given context?

Tags: import, contexts

I have a large `MX` file, which I need to `Get` before running my analysis. The following code puts the symbol in the `Global` context:

```
Begin["Ctx1`"];
Get["dat.mx"];
End[];
```

However, I would like `dat` to be imported into the `Ctx1` context, so that I can refer to it with `Ctx1'dat`. Is there any way to force this behaviour?

Comment: The issue is the .mx file. It’s a binary representation that stores definitions directly, so it actually maintains the symbol context. If it were a .m file it’d be possible to do. Instead you’ll need to reassign the context after the fact—which is something you can read one of Leonid’s answers to learn how to do.

Comment: Looks like an exact duplicate but let me know if you disagree with closing.

Comment: No, I agree that it is a duplicate. This question can be closed.